# PDE and initial-value problems

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I proceed with my PDE class and got some (new) exercises to solve. Some I did solve, the following one I got problems with.

The $\textbf{exercise}$ has two parts and goes as follows. Let $$\begin{cases} u_t + \frac{\partial f(u)}{\partial x} = 0 & \,\text{in}\; \mathbb{R}\times (0, \infty) \\ u(x, 0) = u_0(x) & \text{in}\; \mathbb{R} \end{cases}$$ be the given IVP.

$\textit{First}$, show that for all $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ exists some $T > 0$, such that $$ \begin{cases} \gamma'(t) = f'(u(\gamma(t), t)) & t\in (0, T) \\ 
\gamma(0) = x_0 \end{cases}$$ has a unique solution provided that $u \in C^1(\mathbb{R} \times [0, \infty))$, $u_0 \in C^1(\mathbb{R})$ and $f \in C^2(\mathbb{R})$. Furthermore, show that the map $t \mapsto u(\gamma(t), t)$ is constant on $(0, T]$ and that $\gamma$ is linear.

$\textit{Second}$, now let $f(u) = \frac{1}{2}u^2$, $u_0 \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ and $u_0(x) = 1$ for $x < -1$ and $u_0(x) = 0$ for $x = 1$. Show that there is no classical solution to the IVP above for all $t$. Which condition could one pose on $u_0$ to ensure that the solution to the IVP exists for all $t > 0$?

My **thoughts** on this one are as follows.

With regard to the $\textit{first}$ part, there is a hint given to use the Picard-Lindelof theorem. Since $\gamma$ only depends on $t$ the Picard-Lindelof theorem would tell me that there exists a unique solution provided that the RHS is continuous in all and Lipschitz-continuous in the second variable. Continuity is clear on account of the functions $u, f$ belonging to $C^1$ and $C^2$ respectivly. However, I do not think I can prove Lipschitz-continuity by definition since there is no concrete function $f$ given. However, I was taught that being continuously partially differentiable in the second variable implies Lipschitz-continuity? But isn't the second variable $\gamma$ here? How could I infer something about it? 
Also I do not a have clue how to show neither that the map $t \mapsto u(\gamma(t), t)$ is constant nor that it is linear. I suppose the latter follows from the former in some way since linearity implies a constant derivative.

To the $\textit{second}$ part, I got also no immanent idea. I suppose that there is some discontinuity when $u_0$ changes from 0 to 1 but I really did not figure it out properly.